# Always same line-height?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there any solution that the height between two lines are always the same?
I mean that text with font size 14px and font size 19px have the same distance.
In the attachted picture you can see an example.
[image: example]

Comment: Are you referring to the actual height of each line or the gap between each line?

Comment: So, `line-height` is not what you need?

Comment: Right, I need something for the gap..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, CSS `line-height`. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/line-height).

E.g.:

```
.big {
  font-size: 19px;
  line-height: 19px;
}

.small {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 19px;
}
```

Comment: Note: Using this method will definitely separate them with the same distance, but it's impossible to know the value this distance

Comment: Is there any solution for the height auf the gap?

Answer (score 0):

A better solution for keeping line height consistent would be to style the body tag with your desired heights.  **Note as a rule of thumb you should only be using pt and em in sizing your font/leading (leading is the typography term for line height)

```
body{
      font-size: Xem;
      line-height: Yem;
}
```

Then when you have certain sections that need different leading values you can style them with a class like CSS is suppose to be used.

```
.tightStory{
  font-size: Xem;
  line-height: Xem;
}
.looseStory{
  font-size: Xem;
  line-height: Zem;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: this is also assumed that all the text appears in the same DOM container such as a <span> or <div>

Answer (score 0):

You can set `line-height` to a specific value, even in pixels, e.g. `* { line-height: 21px }`, though this is very rigid and tends to cause problems sooner or later. For texts in, say, font sizes of 14px and 19px, you should really use different line heights. If you explain why you would want to use the same line height, there might be a good solution to the original problem.

Setting line height does *not* set consistent spacing as in your image, which shows the distance between the baseline of text and the uppercase top line of the next line. Line height is the distance between baselines of text. The visual empty space between lines varies by font and by characters (think about lines containing letters like a, x, s only versus lines containing loads of characters like Ê, Å, g, Q). The uppercase top line, i.e. the maximum level of uppercase letters without diacritics, varies a lot by font.